# Maven local repository not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Hello I'm not a java developer but I have do mantenation a java software on my company that use maven.

so I have donwload the source from bitbucket and trying to open it on eclipse.
so I donwloaded and install jdk 1.8, weblogic 12.1.3, maven, and eclipse.

when I tried to open the project on eclipse the pom.xml have an error that I can't resolve, here is how the pom is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>inscricoes-cursos-backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>inscricoes-backend</name>
    <parent> <!-- line with error  -->
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>wls-common</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>gerador-boleto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.org.MyCompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>gerador-boleto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>inscricoes-cursos-backend</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
                <!-- You can find and redefine the following variables in the parent 
                    pom file. oracleMiddlewareHome oracleServerUrl oracleUsername oraclePassword 
                    oracleServerName -->
                <configuration>
                    <middlewareHome>${oracleMiddlewareHome}</middlewareHome>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!--Deploy the application to the server -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <user>******</user>
                            <password>*****</password>                  <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                            <target>ms_2</target>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <name>${project.build.finalName}</name>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have no clue what I have to do to solve it I'm pretty sure it is a easy but cant understand nothing in this pom.xml.

the error message is

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   br.org.hospitalalemao:auditoria-automatizada:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
>   find com.oracle.weblogic.archetype:wls-common:pom:12.1.3-0-0 in
>   https://  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at   wrong local POM

and what I have tried to do was, reinstall maven, delete .m2 folder, redownload project, use a relative path, and format my computer and reinstall everything and nothing worked.I simply can't understand what is wrong and why.

Comment: Formatting your computer is a bit of an extreme reaction to a Maven build failing :/

Comment: You need to add Oracle's Maven Repo to your list of repos. http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9012

Answer (score 0):

You need to maually install  `wls-common.12.1.3-0-0.pom` to your local maven repository using command `mvn install:install-file`. You should be able to find the pom file from your weblogic istallation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `.lastUpdated` files from `.m2` repository, after of that, you can try to force update of snapshot dependencies, use the following command

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks alot guy I used ravthiru answer as startpoin and that was the solution, I will just posto exactly all I did cause maybe it could be helpfull for anothers begginers in java like me.

Firt of all I configure the environment variables 
M2_HOME like below.(C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0 <-- where my maven folder is "instaled")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN1gb.png)

then used the variable in path. like below (very similar to java_home variable)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OETZ.png)

now I can use mvn command on prompt command.

then I was to the folder C:\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.1.3 (here is where my weblogic is instaled. and I ran this commands.

```
 mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.jar

 mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=C:\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home -DoverwriteParent=true

 mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.1.3-0-0
```

special attention to second command where u have to use the oracle home in other cases it could be diferent.

well thanks again to everyone that spend a bit of time to help me.